# How can I create an embeded HTML template using <script type="text/template"> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to create HTML templates that can be called form jQuery using script tags and then be able to show the HTML using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/template">
   <div id="new-post">
     <form>
       <label>Post Title</label>
       <input type="text" id="post-title"/>
       <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
     </form>
   </div>
</script>
```

I have found other post on stackoverflow.com, but none are what I'm looking for. Any advice on how to get this working would be appreciated.

Comment: I cant find the template mime type from http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html

Comment: Check out this article from John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: There is not one, it's a way to have the browser ignore the contents of the script tag and then call it when you need it.

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying should work OK.  If you have something like this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="post-template">
  <div id="new-post">
    <form>
      <label>Post Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="post-title"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

You should be able to do this to extract the template:

```
var template = $('#post-template').html();
```

Better yet, look into using jQuery templates.  See [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/) for a good overview of how they work.

Comment: Have a look at Zaarly.com source code. They have a number of pop-up windows that are driven by script tags with this feature. I'm wanting to implement something similar.

Comment: Link is now broken. See [here](http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as well as some of the other Ajax calls:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```