# how to get a dom element from a template not html

Tags: javascript, templates

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaKACEM/8zdFM/12/)
at first try the script as is and then comment the last line and uncomment the one before it that will give me the functionality i want but with the wrong data, basically i want to grub a template and insert data into it and the insert it before another element in the page.
the problem is that the method that i'm using requires me to use an object or elementNode to insert it but after fetching the template i'm left with html wich result in an error :

> Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

the html:

```
<section class="container well">
    <header></header>    
    <section id="section">
        <h4 id="heading">heading 4</h4>
        <div id="div_1" class="divs">
            <a href="#">file_1.jpg</a>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right">&#10006;</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div_2" class="divs">
            <a href="#">file_2.jpg</a>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right">&#10006;</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div_3" class="divs">
            <a href="#">file_3.jpg</a>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right">&#10006;</button>
        </div>
        <div id="div_4" class="divs">
            <a href="#">file_4.jpg</a>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right">&#10006;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right add">
                 Add items
            </button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
<script type="template" id="template">
    <div id="{{id}}">
        <a href="#">{{fileName}}</a>
    </div>
</script>​
```

my javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    target   = document.getElementById($('.divs')[0].id);
    template = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
    div      = template
                       .replace(/{{id}}/g, '0')
                       .replace(/{{fileName}}/g, 'file_0');
    //target.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('AZERTY'), target);
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target);
});
```

the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaKACEM/8zdFM/12/) again and thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot insert `div`, which is a string containing HTML code, into the DOM as if it were an element. Instead, you could create another div and set its `innerHTML`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    target   = document.getElementById($('.divs')[0].id);
    template = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
    div      = template
                        .replace(/{{id}}/g, '0')
                        .replace(/{{fileName}}/g, 'file_0');
    outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    outerDiv.innerHTML = div;
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(outerDiv, target);
});
```

As noted by a comment on another answer, you may want to skip having a containing div within the template, as you will end up with two divs unnecessarily. Instead you could have simply

```
    <a href="#">{{fileName}}</a>
```

as the template and then

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = '0';
div.innerHTML = template.replace(/{{fileName}}/g, 'file_0');
target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target);
```

in the script. Another alternative is simply to insert the HTML string directly into the target:

```
    target.innerHTML = div + target.innerHTML;
```

Comment: the method of inserting the HTML string directly into the target will not work because i'm inserting the HTML string between a h4 element and a div element it's not just after every thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article - with several links and lots of good advice - about manipulating templates with jQuery:

- [How can I create an embeded HTML template using <script type="text/template"> using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932694/how-can-i-create-an-embeded-html-template-using-script-type-text-template-us)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.add').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      target   = document.getElementById($('.divs')[0].id);
      template = document.querySelector('#template').html();
      div      = template.replace(/{{id}}/g, '0').replace(/{{fileName}}/g, 'file_0');
      divtag = document.createElement('div');
      divtag.innerHTML = div;
      divtag.id = template.id;
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(divtag, target);
 }
```

This should work

Comment: Best not to set `divtag.id = template.id` - that would create two elements with the same id.

Comment: If you're going to use this you might want to skip putting the <div> in the template altogether.

Comment: @james yeah if i'm gonna use this i'll just create the element in javascript and don't use the template at all what i want is a template based solution that did not involve element creation with javascript, and no template plugin too, i'm already using this template system in my project i don't think i'm going to change it now.

Comment: No, my point was to not include the wrapping <div> inside the template, but sure put the div's contents in the template.  Example: `<script type="template" id="template">
        <a href="#">{{fileName}}</a>
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer :

code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    target   = document.getElementById($('.divs')[0].id);
    template = document.querySelector('#template').innerHTML;
    div      = template
                        .replace(/{{id}}/g, '0')
                        .replace(/{{fileName}}/g, 'file_0.jpg');
    new_div  = document.createElement('div');
    new_div.setAttribute('class', 'divs');
    new_div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + i);
    new_div.innerHTML = div;
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(new_div, target);
});
```

​
thanks to stuart.